# Jasper Reports image size is wrong using "Real Size"

Tags: image-processing, jasper-reports, ireport

I have been battling with this for some time.  My JPG images appear too big in jasper reports exports (internal iReports viewer, export to PDF, etc...).  They are about 30% bigger on my computer screen and on paper printout then they are in a web browser, gimp, MS Picture Manager, etc...  Example image attached.

I am using JasperReports 3.6.1/ iReports 3.6.1.  Any ideas also much appreciated.  One note, my SVG images are exported at the correct size using:

```
<image scaleImage="RetainShape" isUsingCache="false">
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="380" height="31" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
        <imageExpression class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRenderable"> <![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.BatikRenderer.getInstance(new java.io.File($P{imagepath} + cool_image.svg))]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

[image: here is the image]

Comment: Also -- using HTML export from iReports 3.6.1, it is clear what is happening.  The JPEG itself does not grow (get resized) but the img tag has a width that is 56% larger (281 px image width at 72 dpi, img tag has width 496 px)  this with image scaling set to "clip".  any ideas, anyone?